# laravel 5.1 routes error message

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Working with laravel 5.1

Whenever i go to `mywebsite.com/home` i get redirected to `auth/login` path but it loads this error message. Im not sure whats causing this issue, everything is still pretty much out of the box. Im not sure what im overlooking 
`MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`

Here is my `routes.php` file

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Authentication routes
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
Route::controllers(['password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

// Using A Route Closure
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
    Route::auth();
}]);
```

Here is my `HomeController.php` file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            return view('home');  
        }

        return view('auth/login');
    }
}
```

My `HomeController.php` index function is pretty striaght forward. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
```

should be

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your Routes file. Your Routes file should be

```
 <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Authentication routes
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
Route::controllers(['password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

// Using A Route Closure
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
    Route::auth();
}]);
```

Hopefully This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel's Authentication module to ease out your work, you should take a look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart

You will be able to define your own redirects and paths.

You might also want to

- Check your `Authenticate.php` middleware under `Http/Middlewares` folder, you will find the guest redirect there
- In your `HomeController.php` constructor you have set the ´auth´ middleware, hence anyone who visits `/home` and is not logged will be redirected to the URL set in the `Authenticate.php` middleware

Now from my own experience I would recommend you using Laravel's authentication helpers to move faster, those are well-built and safe to use rather than re-building the wheel, you know?

Building your own Authentication process can be REAAAALLLY boring unless you want to get your hands dirty with code and testing.